# move semantics with temps allocated with new

Tags: c++11, c++14

I'm just wondering if move semantics are restricted to syntax style B.
More specifically, with style B the object is created on the stack and moved.  With style A, the object is created on the heap, but it seems can't be moved.

The question very specifically is, can you use move semantics such that the **temp** is created with NEW?  If so, how?

```
//move c'tor
A(A&& other) : num(other.num), s(other.s){
   other.num = 0;
   other.s = nullptr;     //dyn alloc obj
}
```

If you do this, it doesn't work (syntax style A).

```
A a2(new A("blah"));        //error
A a2(move(new A("blah")));  //error
```

This is ok (syntax style B)

```
A a2(A("blah"));            //uses c'tor once
A a2(move(A("blah")))       //uses c'tor followed by move c'tor
```

Comment: like `A* a1 = new A("blah"); A a2 = A(*a1);` ?

Comment: In A, you are passing _pointers_ as arguments to constructors of `A`. These constructors does not accept pointers, that's why errors are triggered.

Comment: `A a2(move(A("blah")));` this makes no sense. `std::move` is for casting its argument to _rvalue_, but `A("blah")` is rvalue already. You just hinder copy elision optimizations here.

Comment: Exactly, the move was put there just to see what it does.  Since copy elision exists there is not really a way to trigger the move c'tor without move.  Why trigger it? just to see that it works.  It isn't as efficient, yes.

Comment: @code You can also disable copy elision to trigger move constructor here without invoking `std::move`. With GCC, that's achieved by `-fno-elide-constructors` command line option.

Comment: I see, thank you Daniel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confused about a number of things, so I'll try to shed some light. You probably know most of this already.

*Move semantics* were designed to allow objects to transfer ownership of their data to another object. This was motivated largely to avoid copying from temporary objects that didn't need it.

The *move constructor* is much like the copy constructor, `A(const A&)`, but only accepts a non-const xvalue of the same type, `A(A&&)` (think of it as an e**x**piring value). Therefore, this constructor can be invoked when given something like a return value from a function or a variable moved via `std::move`.

Now, the function `std::move` in itself is a bit of a misnomer, it doesn't actually *do* anything. All it does it cast a `T` or `T&` into a `T&&`.

To address your question directly, nothing I've mentioned is specific to where the moving object is located, but it *is* specific about the types. `A("blah")` calls the constructor with automatic memory and returns that `A`. `new A("blah")` on the other-hand calls the constructor with dynamic memory and returns a *pointer* to that `A`, ergo an `A*`. So your syntax A is not trying to invoke the move constructor, but another constructor like `A(A*)`.

To move from an object referenced by a pointer, all you need to do is derefence and move:

```
A* a1 = new A("blah");
A a2(std::move(*a1));
```

There's nothing stopping you from defining a constructor like `A(A*)`, but that shouldn't be needed and isn't recommended for using move semantics.

Also, your syntax B comments are incorrect; both are a value-constructor `A("blah")` followed by the move-constructor `A(A&&)`; the `std::move` doesn't add anything here.

Comment: vu, the b comments are correct.  Using newest GCC with c++14.  First B line calls only c'tor and only once.  It does not use move.  Prob compiler elision.  The second line calls c'tor once to create the temp and then the move c'tor.  The move is required to trigger a move.  Obviously pointless with gcc as the first line is more efficient.  A a2(move(*new A("Blah")), calls c'tor once then move c'tor.  Can create temp in const param, no need for a1 var.  Ofcourse, this syntax is ugly.  I guess the question is, is there a point to create the temp with new in these examples?

Comment: Granted, elision is something I omitted. The reason you'd use a temporary, instead of something like `A a2(*(new A("blah"))`, is that anything allocated with `new` needs to be `delete`d. Moving the object the pointer points to doesn't change that.

Comment: Ahhh.  That is logical.  So there is really no valid reason to use new.